# Issues with changing locale in react-admin: language package "implicitly has an 'any' type"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-admin

Im trying to follow [this](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Translation.html) official guide on how to do internationalization in react-admin. I install the language pack using `npm install aor-language-swedish`, and change from `aor` to `ra` in index.js of `aor-language-swedish` in order to make it work it react-admin instead of admin on REST (I have also tried the English pack whcih is natively supported in react-admin, but I get the same error described below).

I then try to do 
    import swedishMessages from "aor-language-swedish"; 
in my `App.js` but upon hovering the import, i get the error:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'aor-language-swedish'. 
'c:/Users/ssm/Documents/Visual Studio Code/adminui/node_modules/aor- 
language-swedish/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try `npm install @types/aor-language-swedish` if it exists or add a new 
declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'aor-language- 
swedish';
```

What could be causing this error? I have looked around the internet, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this problem was not in fact a problem. Ignoring it seems to work, and remember to change the root key in `index.js` of the package to `ra` instead of `aor` if you are using an older react-admin language module (like Swedish). However, it would be interesting to know why this warning is shown, as I am not using TypeScript. Might it be an extension that is causing this warning?

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting this error it is probably because you're using TypeScript, have you tried to run `npm install --save-dev @types/aor-language-swedish` ?

If this doesn't exist you will have to manually add a typing file, you can follow the following tutorial in order to do so:
https://medium.com/@chris_72272/migrating-to-typescript-write-a-declaration-file-for-a-third-party-npm-module-b1f75808ed2

Comment: I am not using TS in my project, so your link did not work. I also tried the command the error gave, with no further result.